# Validating last digit of CNIC always returns invalid input?

Tags: c

So, I've been trying to validate CNIC because Pakistan requires male CNIC's to end in odd number and female CNIC's to end in even number.
CNIC is stored as a string in a structure containing information about a bank user.
The problem is when i apply the logic, it doesn't seem to work as intended and always prints the invalid CNIC prompt even when it is correctly input.
Here is the relevant code:

```
    struct account//The structure used to store the records
{
  int  mm,dd,yyyy,Deposit;
  long long int accountnum;
  char name[50];
  char address[50];
  char Account[50];
  char CNIC[50];
  char Num[50];
  char gender;
} s[100];

void ValidCNIC(int j) {
    int i = 0, check = 0;
    char ch;
    printf("\n \tCNIC: ");
    fgets(s[j].CNIC,sizeof(s[j].CNIC),stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    while(i < strlen(s[j].CNIC)-1) {
            ch = s[j].CNIC[i];
            if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                    i++;
            }
            else{
                    printf(" \tThe CNIC can contain numbers only!\n");
                    fordelay(1000000000);
                    ValidCNIC(j);

            }
    }
    if (strnlen(s[j].CNIC,sizeof(s[j].CNIC)) < 14)
    {
            printf(" \tThe CNIC is too short\n \tPlease reenter\n");
            fordelay(1000000000);
            ValidCNIC(j);
    }
    else if (strnlen(s[j].CNIC,sizeof(s[j].CNIC)) > 14) {
            printf(" \tThe CNIC is too long\n \tPlease reenter\n");
            fordelay(1000000000);
            ValidCNIC(j);
    }
    int len = strnlen(s[j].CNIC,sizeof(s[j].CNIC));
    if((s[j].gender == 'm') && ((s[j].CNIC[len] !='1')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='3')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='5')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='7')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='9')))
       {
           printf("invalid CNIC, male CNIC must always end in an odd number");
           ValidCNIC(j);
       }
    else if((s[j].gender == 'w') && ((s[j].CNIC[len] !='0')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='2')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='4')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='6')||(s[j].CNIC[len] !='8')))
    {
           printf("Invalid CNIC, female CNIC must end in an even number");
           ValidCNIC(j);
    }
```

Comment: `s[j].CNIC[len]` after `int len = strnlen(s[j].CNIC,sizeof(s[j].CNIC));` will always be zero unless the string is too long because strings in C are terminated by a null-character.

Comment: Also note that `fflush(stdin);` [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: So how should i go about this?

Comment: Instead of `if(ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)` you probably meant `if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')`, which is better written `if(isdigit(ch))`.

Comment: Ah yes thanks I changed it to this better form

Comment: But the initial issue still stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion does not seem well suited to this task.
Consider a loop until the input is ok.
`strspn` can be used to test the input for digits. `index` will be the first character that is not a digit. Following `fgets` and all digits, that character should be a newline ( `'\n'`).
Use modulus ( '% 2') to determine if the last digit is odd or even.
This is not exactly what is needed but should give ideas that can be adapted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 50

int main ( void) {
    char CNIC[LENGTH] = "";
    int ok = 0;
    int gender = 'm';

    while ( ! ok) {
        printf ( "enter CNIC\n");
        fgets ( CNIC, sizeof CNIC, stdin);
        size_t index = strspn ( CNIC, "0123456789");
        if ( 14 <= index && '\n' == CNIC[index]) {
            int mod = CNIC[index - 1] % 2;
            if ( 'm' == gender) {
                if ( mod ) {//odd
                    ok = 1;
                }
                else {
                    printf ( "male CNIC must be odd\n");
                }
            }
            if ( 'w' == gender) {
                if ( ! mod ) {//even
                    ok = 1;
                }
                else {
                    printf ( "female CNIC must be odd\n");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf ( "enter digits only, at least 14. try again\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! However what does strspn do here?

Answer (score 1):

You ought not take input in your validation function; just validate.   Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int
isValidCNIC(const char *cnic, char gender)
{
        size_t len = 0;
        const char *s = cnic;
        char c;
        if( gender != 'm' && gender != 'f' ){
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid gender: %c\n", gender);
                return 0;
        }
        while( *cnic ){
                len += 1;
                if( ! isdigit(c = *cnic++) ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid character %c\n", s, c);
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        if( len != 14 ){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: too %s\n", s, len < 14 ? "short" : "long");
                return 0;
        }
        if( ((c - '0') % 2) != ( gender == 'm' ) ){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid parity\n", s);
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}

int
main(void)
{
        struct test { char *cnic; int gender; } t[] = {
                { "34576271345678", 'f' },
                { "34576271345677", 'm' },
                { "34576271345678", 'm' },
                { "3457627134678", 'm' },
                { "345762713456788", 'm' },
                { "3457a271345788", 'k' },
                { NULL, 0 }
        };
        for( struct test *p = t; p->cnic; p++ ){
                if( isValidCNIC( p->cnic, p->gender) ){
                        printf("valid: %s\n", p->cnic);
                }
        }
}
```

But note that `strspn` does most of the work that you are trying to do, and you could refactor to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int
isValidCNIC(const char *cnic, char gender)
{
        char err[256] = "";
        size_t len = strspn(cnic, "0123456789");
        const char *s = cnic;

        if( gender != 'm' && gender != 'f' ){
                strcat(err, "invalid gender, ");
        }
        if( cnic[len] ){
                strcat(err, "invalid character, ");
        }
        if( len != 14 ){
                strcat(err, len < 14 ? "too short, " : " too long, ");
        }
        if( ((cnic[len - 1] - '0') % 2) != ( gender == 'm' ) ){
                strcat(err, "invalid parity, ");
        }
        if( *err ){
                err[strlen(err) - 2] = '\0';
                fprintf(stderr, "%s, %c: %s\n", s, gender, err);
        }
        return !*err;
}

int
main(void)
{
        struct test { char *cnic; int gender; } t[] = {
                { "34576271345678", 'f' },
                { "34576271345677", 'm' },
                { "34576271345678", 'm' },
                { "3457627134678", 'm' },
                { "345762713456788", 'm' },
                { "3457a271345788", 'k' },
                { NULL, 0 }
        };
        for( struct test *p = t; p->cnic; p++ ){
                if( isValidCNIC( p->cnic, p->gender) ){
                        printf("valid: %s\n", p->cnic);
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `'0'` and `'9'` instead of 48 and 57.

Do *not* recursively call `ValidCNIC` from within itself. This can lead to infinite recursion

Add an (e.g.) outer that checks an error flag/value and loops if there is an error

Using `s[j].CNIC[i]` everywhere is cumbersome. Better to set (e.g.) `char *cnic = s[j].CNIC;` and use that.

No need to call `strlen` in the loop. Just call it once and save the value.

Your even/odd check can be simplified

---

Here's a refactored version. It is annotated. It compiles but I've not tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//The structure used to store the records
struct account {
    int mm, dd, yyyy, Deposit;
    long long int accountnum;
    char name[50];
    char address[50];
    char Account[50];
    char CNIC[50];
    char Num[50];
    char gender;
} s[100];

#define ERRSET(_fmt) \
    { \
        err = _fmt; \
        break; \
    }

void
ValidCNIC(int j)
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    const char *err;

    while (1) {
        printf("\n \tCNIC: ");

        struct account *acct = &s[j];
        fgets(acct->CNIC, sizeof(acct->CNIC), stdin);
        char *cnic = acct->CNIC;

        // strip the newline
        cnic[strcspn(cnic,"\n")] = 0;

        size_t cnlen = strlen(cnic);

        err = NULL;

        do {
            // ensure CNIC has only digits
            for (i = 0;  i < cnlen;  ++i) {
                ch = cnic[i];
                if ((ch < '0') || (ch > '9'))
                    ERRSET(" \tThe CNIC can contain numbers only!\n");
            }
            if (err != NULL)
                break;

            // ensure CNIC length is correct
            if (cnlen < 14)
                ERRSET(" \tThe CNIC is too short\n \tPlease reenter\n");
            if (cnlen > 14)
                ERRSET(" \tThe CNIC is too long\n \tPlease reenter\n");

            int isodd = cnic[cnlen - 1];
            isodd -= '0';
            isodd %= 2;

            // ensure even/odd of CNIC matches gender
            switch (acct->gender) {
            case 'm':
                if (! isodd)
                    ERRSET("invalid CNIC, male CNIC must always end in an odd number");
                break;
            case 'w':
                if (isodd)
                    ERRSET("Invalid CNIC, female CNIC must end in an even number");
                break;
            }
        } while (0);

        // no errors
        if (err == NULL)
            break;

        // show the error
        printf("%s",err);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> It still doesn't seem to work either, keeps giving the same prompt of Invalid CNIC. – Bas_Anar

Oops, my bad ... I forgot to remove the newline after the `fgets`. I've edited the example code above.

> Btw what does that preprocessor directive do? – Bas_Anar

The macro arg is `_fmt`. The macro just does:

```
err = _fmt;
break;
```

where it is used.

So, it sets an error string and breaks out of the containing loop.

At the bottom, if `err` is `NULL`, there is no error and we're done.

Otherwise, it prints the error string and the outer loop reprompts the user.

Here's an example of the expanded macro text:

```
// ensure CNIC length is correct
if (cnlen < 14) {
    err = " \tThe CNIC is too short\n \tPlease reenter\n";
    break;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work either, keeps giving the same prompt of Invalid CNIC.

Comment: Btw what does that preprocessor directive do?